# Dynamodb: unable to access nested objects and array of objects

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynogels

I am new to DynamoDb. I am trying to access an object inside the array:

Created a new item in a table-

```
survey.create({
      survey_name: 'Cycle',
      description: 'Describe me',
      test:[{
        title:'hello1'
      },{
        title:'hello2'
      }]
      }, function (err, survey) {
         if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
          console.log('created', survey.get('survey_name'));
        }
      });
```

I am not to able to fetch "test[n].title", getting 0 results.

```
survey.query('Cycle')
     .filter('test.title').equals('hello2') //Tried it with test[0].title also
     .exec((err,data)=>{
         if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            else{
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
```

Also, I want to retrieve a part(json) of the item of a table ie. 'test' if its possible

Comment: Using dynogels: https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

Comment: What are you using for querying? AWS-SDK?

Comment: Oh.. in DynamoDB, you can't query with nested properties.

Comment: So, there is no possible way with which i can query test[0].title ?

Comment: Can you post your table schema (e.g. post your table create)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying DynamoDB using filters requires the key you are filtering on to be the `top level` key. You cannot filter using a nested object key.

Comment: Is there any other property or function, with which i can query nested property (ie. test[1].title or test[0].title) ?

Comment: Basically, i want to filter out sub document ie test object.. 
In mongodb.. it can be achieved by using this:

db.survey.findOne({ test: { $elemMatch : { title: 'hello2' }} })..
 expected result is : survey_name: 'Cycle', description: 'Describe me', test:[{ title:'hello1' }] 

Is it possible in dynamodb?